# Issue with loading Tidyverse in RStudio

Tags: r, tidyverse

How to do i resolve the following code error?

```
library(tidyverse)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
>
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tidyselect', details:
>
> call: is_string(x)
>
> error: object 'rlang_is_string' not found
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.5.3

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, this looks suspiciously like a silent installation error

Comment: I'd start by quitting R (or RStudio), restarting and reinstalling `tidyverse`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated my R to 3.6.0 and reinstalled tidyverse. Seems to work =)

Answer (score 4):

For persistent errors of type, first, ensure you are working with the latest version of R. The [installr](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/) package is a very convenient way to do this.

Then, start new R session (ideally, not in RStudio).

Uninstall tidyverse, tidyselect, and rlang

```
    # if you are using multiple libraries, you may need to specify libpath, 
    # using the following: lib="~/R/win-library/3.6"        
    # you can check using the .libPaths() command

    remove.packages("rlang") 
    remove.packages("tidyselect")
    remove.packages("tidyverse")
```

and, reinstall them one by one with dependencies = TRUE

```
    install.packages("rlang", dependencies = TRUE)
    install.packages("tidyselect", dependencies = TRUE)
    install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter a similar problem like you, which I'm unable to load the tidyverse too.
**Hope this discuss from the tidyverse github issues maybe relevant to you.**

https://github.com/tidyverse/googledrive/issues/275

> **Here's one of our typical explanations of this. Note that this is not specific to googledrive or rlang. It's an R + Windows gotcha**. I suspect  for you is rlang (at least).
>   Please note that on Windows, it is very important to quit or restart
>   all R processes before upgrading , because if any R process has
>   loaded, it will keep the .dll file open and the installer will not be
>   able to overwrite .dll. The error message when this happens is very
>   easy to overlook, and the new version will be partially installed: the
>   package description and R code will be updated but the compiled code
>   (in .dll) will not.